# If element does not exist, end the job [Dealing with pagination]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, exception, web-scraping

I have a page where the number of elements to loop through is not easily known.  As such I’ve made the job loop through Href “a” (364 matches) and when it cannot find the Next button, I am wanting the job to come to an end.

```
I have tried:
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

#except IOError:
    #pass
#except OSError:
    #pass
```

As well as other variations and indenting.

My full code is [here](http://textuploader.com/dl1df) (it does not allow me to post it here fully due to character limit)

Comment: Provided `try`/`except` block should work as expected. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Andersson Well it seems to create an error when the Next button is not found.  I'd rather it - when it can't find the element it finishes the job so to speak.

Comment: @Andersson https://ibb.co/ezBkMR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should allow you to close browser and WebDriver session once you reach last page

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test that now.  Will it close the driver and stop the job or will it close the job and continue rest of job creating errors.

Comment: It should break "Selenium" part of script. If there is more code (not related to WebDriver) to execute, it will be executed, but if not, job should be closed

Comment: Yeah it does that.  Is there no stop job or skip parts of the job command.  I guess I will just have to put up with error notifications if no way around it

Comment: I might look into it further, but I suppose at least the job runs as expected despite error message.